# how to embed or share a gits in my blog wordpress?

Tags: github

I am new in worpdress but I would like to share my code gits in my blog wordpress.

so then I made a gits in github:

(this code it is just a example for this question)

[image: done]

but when I try to share my gits in wordpress I got this:

[image: error]

does anyone know how  I can fix that and share my code in wordpress?

note:** my blog wordpress is in a hosting web i dont use the platform from wordpress I have installed the wordpress in my blog. **

Comment: Do not emebed it via wp embed as that is meant for media files mostly and not for code. For code I suggest you use embed script snippet by gist see on top right corner of your gist screenshot.. embed: just before : download zip

Comment: how can I do that? do you have a tutorial about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot, there's an **Embed** option with `<script>` tag in it. Take that code and add it to a *Custom HTML* block.